# Why does having a return statement in my try block make the 'else' statement unreachable?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I'm learning exception handling in Python3 and can't seem to understand why the else statement in my if-else block is unreachable when using return in the try block.

```
def simple_division() -> float:
    """
    :return:  the quotient of a / b
    """

    a, b = _git_int()

    if a == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        try:
            return a / b
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Uh, you can't divide by zero, bud.")
        else:
            print("This should execute if no exceptions are raised, right? but it doesn't")
        finally:
            print("This should execute either way.")
```

I spent some time debugging in order to figure out that the return statement in the try block was at fault... and I now understand that doing something like this circumvents the problem:

```
def simple_division() -> float:
    """
    :return:  the quotient of a / b
    """

    a, b = _git_int()

    if a == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        try:
            answer = a / b
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Uh, you can't divide by zero, bud.")
        else:
            print("This DOES work")
            return answer
        finally:
            print("This should execute either way.")
```

But I haven't yet found any documentation explaining why you can't have a return statement in a try block. Could someone explain this to me? What would be the best practice here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, AFAIK. It'll run perfectly fine if you try running it. Your linter doesn't seem to know that.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi 
Initially I thought so as well, but running the code does prove it's unreachable. I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Once you `return`, code execution in the function stops unless there's an exception in a `try/except` block, in which case `except` will run instead of returning.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question. There's nothing _wrong_ with your original code -- it always works. If there is no error, `a / b` is returned immediately in the `try` block, so your `print` in the `else` block never runs. If you just want to return the result of the division (i.e. if you remove the prints), there's no difference between the two codes.

Comment: @MattDMo
Thanks! I had a feeling it was a fundamental misunderstanding of how the language works. Disheartening every time, but at least I learned something.